# Spotlight randomly chose Chinese as dictionary language after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: spotlight, dictionary

After upgrading to El Capitan, suddenly Spotlight dictionary searches only show results in Chinese (I think). I have absolutely no idea why it chose Chinese, as I am not a user of that language.

This happens when my keyboard is set to Norwegian (as usual), but when it is set to US English, the dictionary seems to correctly give English results.

What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: For the record: I'm having this issue as well, except Spotlight is giving me Korean results, but for some reason only for "Yellowstone"...

Comment: Also for the record: I'm getting results in Korean, Japanese, Spanish, French, Chinese and a few other languages for arbitrary words; sometimes re-searching these words return the definition in a different language!